# Using vue-router-sitemaps for laravel vue spa

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, sitemap

Hello I am trying to make a dynamic sitemap for [Laravel vue spa](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa) by using [Vue router sitemap](https://github.com/40818419/vue-router-sitemap) but I am unable to do it perfectly as I keep getting an error in the console. Either the docs is incomplete or I am just not doing it right but this is the error I keep getting in the console, please help

It pops up an error saying `fs` dependency was not found like

`This dependency was not found:`

`* fs in ./node_modules/sitemap/lib/sitemap.js, ./node_modules/vue-router-sitemap/dist/index.js`